# JSFIDDLE not working on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a JSFIDDLE and trying to get it to work on my web form but it is not woorking. Can anyone please tell me what mistake i am making. The JSFIDDLE is working perfectly fine but i am not able to get it to work at my page only. This is the link to the fiddle: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywzjv/2/)

And this is how i am trying to use it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var devices = ['computer', 'router']
var device_types = {
    'computer': ['laptop', 'desktop'],
    'router': ['wireless', 'bluetooth']
}

var brands = {
    'laptop': ['HP', 'DELL'],
    'desktop': ['Apple', 'MAC'],
    'wireless':['Foo','Bar'],
    'bluetooth':['Grren','Blue']
}


function createOptions(arr) {
    var html = ['<option >--select--</option>'];
    $.each(arr, function(i, item) {
        html.push('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>')
    });
    return html.join('');
}

var mainOptions = createOptions(devices)

$(function() {
    $("input[type=button][value=Add]").click(function(e) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('sel').value; i++) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var j = 1;

            var newDiv = $('<div class="row">').appendTo("#dropbox");
            $("<select class='devices has_dependents'>").attr("name", "input1_" + j).append(mainOptions).appendTo(newDiv)

            $("<select class='device_types has_dependents'>").attr("name", "input2_" + j).appendTo(newDiv)
            $("<select class='brands'>").attr("name", "input3_" + j).appendTo(newDiv)
            $("<input>").attr("name", "input4_" + j).appendTo(newDiv);
            $("<button>").text("Remove").appendTo(newDiv).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().remove();
            })
            j++;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('change', 'select.has_dependents', function() {
        var val = $(this).val(),
            option_obj;
        if ($(this).is('.devices')) {
            option_obj = device_types;
        } else {
            option_obj = brands;
        }


        var options = createOptions( option_obj[val]);


        $(this).next().html(options)
    })
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="01" >01</option>
        <option value="02" >02</option>
        <option value="03" >03</option>
        <option value="04" >04</option>
        <option value="05" >05</option>
        <option value="06" >06</option>
        <option value="07" >07</option>
        <option value="08" >08</option>
        <option value="09" >09</option>
        <option value="10" >10</option>
        <option value="11" >11</option>
        <option value="12" >12</option>
        <option value="13" >13</option>
        <option value="14" >14</option>
        <option value="15" >15</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Add" />

    <div id="dropbox"></div>
</form>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem might be in javascript somewhere.. you should take a look at the javascript console.

Comment: If testing locally, does your browser have javascript disabled perhaps? If you happen to be testing in IE, it may block the script until you dismiss a warning... I had that.

Comment: How about a link to your page where it doesn't work versus jsFiddle where it does?

Comment: That code of my page is mentioned in the question and link to that JSFIDDLE is this : http://jsfiddle.net/Ywzjv/2/

Comment: My point is, since it works in the fiddle, that doesn't help us help you. If you could link to your page where it **doesn't** work then it would be more helpful.

Comment: actually this is my page code and i am not using a website hosting to use it. it is on wamp server installed on my computer.

Comment: @j08691 if i can get it to a hosting temporary will you be interested to help me?

Comment: Sure. I just need to see it actually fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 67 there is a non-visual character just after the ')'

```
})<right here is a none visual character>
</script>
```

Edit:
heres a link to the fixed code:

http://pastebin.com/8n8fkgMy

Comment: and what am i in a need to do to fix it ??

Comment: simply delete the entire line 67 and retype it :)

Comment: if u put your cursor just after the } press delete until line 67 looks like '}<script>' then press ')' and it should work

Comment: @Harsh you didn't by chance copy the line, delete and copy it back in to save yourself the typing, did you?

Comment: i did this as well, but NO. Also i looked to page source and there was a space between "}"and ")" on line 66, so i deleted that space the same way as you asked for line 67 but still nothing

Comment: @ultranaut no while deleting this space on line 67 and 66, i deleted and retyped the braces but yes while first time i copied the complete code from jsfiddle.

Comment: Thnx it's working now, your solution worked, but also what i was missing was "//" in front of the link to js library on line 6. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You've got an illegal character in there from cutting and pasting from jsfiddle, which places zero-width space characters in there for some reason. It displays in vim as `<200b>` following your closing paren on line 67.

Comment: How to fix it ? Believe me it is a Rocket Science for me. I have little knowledge of HTML and very little of PHP and NOTHING on java

Comment: You can either do what @user156230 suggested, or just copy and paste your entire code block up above in your question and replace what you have in your file with it.